# SQL to delete excess rows outside valid sub-range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named "A" which have 2 columns, "A1" and "A2".

I want each unique value in column "A1" to have MAX 2 rows in the table, if a unique value in column "A1" have 5 rows, 3 rows should be deleted.

Which 3 rows to delete is determinated by the lowest values in column "A2".

The table consist of +20 million rows, +300000 unique values in column "A1" and up to 3000 rows per unique value in column "A1".

I have solved this with the following query:

```
with excess as
(
    select
        id,
        row_number() over(partition by A1 order by A2 desc) as rownum
    from
        A
)
delete from excess
where rownum > 2
```

I'm satisfied with this query since it took 8 minutes for the initial batch and ~20 seconds in recurring executions.

Is this the most efficient query to achieve the requirements?

Comment: If at all this question fits better to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ I wonder why this is important at all.Do you often have to execute this delete? If so, why?

Comment: To definitively answer this question requires proving a negative which is impossible.  Thus is it is a matter of opinion and off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with Tim Schmelter. The query itself looks great, but if it is required that there are at most two records per A1, then why are more records written to the table at all?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm solving this for a customer, I have already corrected the insert logic from their systems. Now I have to correct the data with an initial batch and recurring executions until next release cycle. My question is more related to the efficiency of the SQL (Sorry if this is off-topic, I post in dba.stackexchange.com next time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this is is the most efficient query without copying the data into another table because it is making it in a single run against the table instead of joining back to itself. I would suggest that you use "delete top(N)" and keep the number under 5,000, if there are any other consumers of the table. this will attempt to prevent the lock escalation from escalating to a full table lock. it will also free up the tlogs on the server to be reused in between batches. if you do it all in one go, all of the deleted rows have to be accounted for in the tlogs, and the space can't be reused until the statement is complete. I would also suggest creating a composite index on (A1, A2).

if the number of rows that need to be deleted are a significant percentage, it would be faster to copy the rows where rownum <= 2 into a new table. then, drop the original table and rename the new table back to the original. if you have other consumers of the table and/or don't want to copy the data, then this may not be a valid solution.